# Safe to assume Email addresses are unique?

Tags: security, email, authentication

Building an app for schools. Teachers will have classrooms assigned to them. Teachers login via email/password.

We also have district supervisors/administrators who need to easily distribute these classrooms to teachers. Currently I have a feature where they can assign a classroom to an email address, and when a user with that email signs up, it is automatically granted to them.

Is this safe? Or is it possible for two individuals to have the same email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two email accounts cannot have the same email address, but whether multiple individuals are using the same address will depend on the policy of the owner of the domain, or it might be up to individual users for public systems such as Gmail or Hotmail if they want to share their address with others.

Is the app (or a particular deployment of it) restricted to only allow sign-ups from the domain of the school? (e.g. at Example College only alow emails that end in `@example.edu`?)

If so, you should check with the school as it is upto them how emails are distributed and used. If anyone can sign up you should be aware that people *may* share email addresses at certain institutions or that email addresses may be recycled for new teachers if no longer in use.

To make this approach more secure you should:

- Verify the email address of each person that signs up. This can be a confirmation email containing a link with an ID generated by a [cryptographically secure RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). When the user clicks the link `http://www.example.com/confirm.aspx?id=123456qwerty` this will verify that they have access to the email address and grant them access to the classroom.
- Expire the pre-granted rooms after a set number of days. This will reduce the chances of a classroom being granted to any recycled email address.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things jump out to me.

1) You seem to be assigning resources to an account (an email address) before it has been created.  How do you know that the person registering with that email address is the person that you expect?

2) You can only assume that an email address is unique if you control the domain of the email addresses and you enforce uniqueness.  Otherwise it is possible that email addresses will be recycled over time (quite common with corporate email addresses like jsmith@company.com).